# convert single line log to correct format using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a program log value in string (entire log is coming in single line), i would like to convert into multi-line, awk would do this definately but how to loop through in single line ?

I have below code in bash (where `str` containing entire logging string generated by program, in just a single line)

```
str="2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File] 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry 
 - blah blah blah..."
```

```
echo $str|awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" \n "}; { printf "%s %s %s", $1,$2,$3}'
```

The above awk command will do is print initial three values of log text which separated by " - ". but this has to be done in loop since i am expecting output as below, which has date or timestamp and short message and followed by long message strings.

```
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0) 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File] 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0) 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry - blah blah blah...
```

How we can do this using awk?

```
str="2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File] 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry 
 - blah blah blah..."
echo $str|awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" \n "}; { printf "%s %s %s", $1,$2,$3}'
```

Final result expected is:-

```
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0) 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File] 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0) 
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry - blah blah blah...
```

Comment: `entire log is coming in single line` are you sure about that? does the program really print logs in a single line or do you truncate line feeds while assigning its output to a variable?

Comment: Also are you REALLY doing `echo $str` instead of `echo "$str"`? That alone would make it **appear like** your text is all on one line as it'd convert every sequence of white space to a blank char as it'd be passing every non-blank string one at a time to `echo` (after performing globbing, etc.). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: @oguzismail: i am not entire sure about that, it could be possible i am making mistake, i will try Ed Morton suggestion of removing double quotes. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only).

```
echo "$str" | awk '{val=$1;$1="";gsub(/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/,ORS "&");print val $0}'
```

***EDIT:*** Adding @Corentin's comment version too here:

```
echo $str | awk '{print gensub(/.([0-9\/]{10})/, "\n\\1", "g")}'
```

Comment: shorter version : `echo $str | awk '{print gensub(/.([0-9\/]{10})/, "\n\\1", "g")}'`

Comment: @CorentinLimier, sure thank you for letting know, added it now in my solution.

Comment: You should mention that the gensub() version requires gawk (or some versions of mawk) but if you have gawk then [a version that sets RS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55852602/1745001) is better as it then doesn't have to read all of the input in as a single record first.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk

```
awk -vRS='([0-9]{2,4}/?){3}' '{printf $0"\n"RT}' <<<$str
```

tried on gnu sed

```
 sed -E 's/([0-9]{2,4}\/?){3}/\n&/g'<<<$str
```

Comment: wrt the awk answer - that will print blank lines before and after the data and never do `printf $0`, always `printf "%s", $0` instead (imagine the difference if $0 contained printf formatting chars like `%s`). Also, always quote your shell variables - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for input, printf "%s", $0 did not worked (need to check) but sed is fine.. and i am going with it.

Comment: @MateenSyed you didn't say in what way `printf "%s", $0` didn't work so I can't help you much there but to be 100% clear - I wasn't saying that that is the solution to your problem, I was saying that `printf "%s", $0` is how to robustly print **only** `$0` or any other input data as opposed to `printf $0` as in abdans answer. Btw the sed solution that you say worked will add a blank line at the start of the output and, same as the awk one, would fail if any 6 digit number appeared in your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's April, and it's a `bash` string, then a `bash` substitution kludge might be sufficient:

```
echo "${str// 2019/$'\n'2019}"
```

Output:

```
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0)
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File]
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0)
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry
```

Note: Since `bash`'s string substitution is less versatile than `sed` and `awk`'s, this code would fail if it were New Years Eve because the substitution would miss lines starting with `2020/01/01`.  Provided the log lines don't contain the string "*`20`*", (note the leading space), this might be good for the next 80 years:

```
echo "${str// 20/$'\n'20}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
$ str='2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File] 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0) 2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry - blah blah blah...'
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ echo "$str" | awk -v RS='[0-9/]{10} [0-9:]{8} |\n' 'NR>1{print p $0} {p=RT}'
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Start of job execution
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(0, 0, START.0)
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - START - Starting job entry
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - Starting entry [Call_Param_File]
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Main_Cons_Job_edw_cc_sf_accts_assets_feed - exec(1, 0, Call_Param_File.0)
2019/04/24 23:26:42 - Call_Param_File - Starting job entry - blah blah blah...
```